# ¿Como puedo manipular objeto en Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, json, api, ionic, ionic3

En este código implementé la solución del return, también la de poner todo la función en el constructor la implementé pero ninguna me funciono y siempre me asigna un valor undefined, lo que quiero lograr es traer el cliente asignarlo a clienteActual para poder utilizar un atributo descuento que tiene el cliente para utilizarlo en otro función donde también obtenga los productos desde el API y asi pueda usar el descuento del cliente y los precios de los productos para hacer las operacioes pertinente, como puedo lograr eso en IONIC 3?

```js
 //constructor
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient,public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public productosProvider: ProductosProvider, public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public facturasProvider: FacturaProvider, public clientesProvider: ClientesProvider,
    public rutasProvider: RutasProvider, public alertController: AlertController,
    public empresaProvider: EmpresasProvider, public detalleProvider: DetalleProvider
  ) {
    //cargar datos de clientes
   
    this.clienteID = this.navParams.get('id');

    this.clienteActual = this.getCliente(this.clienteID);
    
    console.log(this.clienteActual);
   
  }
  
   getCliente(id:any) {
    this.ClientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
      this.nombre = this.cliente.nombre;
      this.razon = this.cliente.razon;
      this.rutaId = this.cliente.ruta;
      this.descuento = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.descuentot = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.codigo = this.cliente.codigo;
      this.credito = this.cliente.credito;
      this.LAT = this.cliente.LAT;
      this.LONGI = this.cliente.LONGI;
      console.log(this.cliente);
     
      return data;
    })
  }
```

Cuando consulto el api para obtener un elemento especifico, no puedo manipular sus atributos en otros métodos, en el constructor trato de asignar el elemento que retorno el api a la variable this.clienteActual, pero no puedo acceder a sus atributos me dice que son undefined. En el codigo adjunto tengo el metodo que obtiene el cliente desde el provider. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient,
    public ProductosProvider: ProductosProvider, public LoadingController: LoadingController,
    public FacturasProvider: FacturaProvider, public ClientesProvider: ClientesProvider,
    public RutasProvider: RutasProvider, public AlertController: AlertController,
    public EmpresaProvider: EmpresasProvider, public DetalleProvider: DetalleProvider
  ) {
    //cargar datos de clientes
    this.fechadt = this.fechadt;
    this.clienteID = this.navParams.get('id');
    this.nombreEm= this.navParams.get('nombre');
    this.rutaID = this.navParams.get('ruta');
    this.clienteActual = this.getCliente(this.clienteID);
    this.getRuta(this.rutaID);
    this.getEmpresa();

    
    //console.log(this.clienteActual);
    console.log(this.clienteID);
    console.log(this.rutaID);
    this.formatearFecha();
   
  }

 
  //metodo que obtiene el cliente y sus datos para utilizarlos
  getCliente(id:any) {
    this.ClientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
      this.nombre = this.cliente.nombre;
      this.razon = this.cliente.razon;
      this.rutaId = this.cliente.ruta;
      this.descuento = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.descuentot = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.codigo = this.cliente.codigo;
      this.credito = this.cliente.credito;
      this.LAT = this.cliente.LAT;
      this.LONGI = this.cliente.LONGI;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Que tal Gustavo, bienvenido... te recomiendo que  te des una vuelta por [ask] y así puedas mejorar tu pregunta... ya  que estamos seria bueno que subas mas código, ya que lo que pusiste no debe ser todo lo que tu archivo  *.ts*  tiene. Tu error puede estar en otra parte del código, inclusive en el hecho del orden o la devolución  de los datos en los callbacks y promesas usadas.

Comment: Gracias Victor, ya añadi el código donde obtengo el cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo los comentarios que te hice en la pregunta... 
haces un

`this.clienteActual = this.getCliente(this.clienteID);`

Si lo leemos bien, haces que en la variable clienteActual se le asigne el resultado de la función, pero si vemos tu función:

```
//metodo que obtiene el cliente y sus datos para utilizarlos
  getCliente(id:any) {
    this.ClientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
      this.nombre = this.cliente.nombre;
      this.razon = this.cliente.razon;
      this.rutaId = this.cliente.ruta;
      this.descuento = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.descuentot = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.codigo = this.cliente.codigo;
      this.credito = this.cliente.credito;
      this.LAT = this.cliente.LAT;
      this.LONGI = this.cliente.LONGI;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

En ningun momento haces el retorno de un dato para hacer la asignación a la variable que quieres.

Por lo que puedo notar es que tu variable `data` es un objeto, pero despues haces distintas asignaciones a otras variables, así que no se si quieres almacenar en `clienteActual` toda la variable data o solo un dato en especifico....

**Como solución a este problema, en cualquiera de estos casos** seria bueno que la asignacion a esa variable lo hagas dentro de la misma funcion dejando el codigo de esta forma:

```
this.ClientesProvider.getCliente(id).then(data => {
      this.cliente = data;
      this.nombre = this.cliente.nombre;
      this.razon = this.cliente.razon;
      this.rutaId = this.cliente.ruta;
      this.descuento = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.descuentot = this.cliente.descuento;
      this.codigo = this.cliente.codigo;
      this.credito = this.cliente.credito;
      this.LAT = this.cliente.LAT;
      this.LONGI = this.cliente.LONGI;
      console.log(data);

      // ESTA ES LA LINEA QUE AUMENTAMOS
      this.clienteActual = data;
    })
```

y todo ese código ponerlo dentro del constructor(tambien puedes usarlo en `ionViewDidLoad()` pero esto depende de como estes trabajando en tu codigo).

---

**Otra solución, y mucho mas simple todavía**  y es hacer al final de la función un `return data;`

debí haber comenzado por esto, pero era importante hacer notar el error para poder avanzar a las soluciones.

Comment: Como comentario a la respuesta y acotando algo que a futuro tal vez puedas evitar, cuando hagas inyecciones en el constructor procura que las variables que uses no comiencen con mayúsculas...  Al principio haces esto: `public navCtrl: NavController` y esto esta bien.... pero después haces esto: `public ProductosProvider: ProductosProvider` lo que puede ocasionar conflictos con las variables y las clases importadas. Hay que tener en cuenta que por convención las Clases comienzan por mayúsculas, y las variables con minúscula siguiendo un estilo camelCase para poder hacer el código mas legible.

Comment: Gracias por tus sugerencias, sin embargo al hacer todas y hacer un console.log(this.clienteActual), sigue devolviendo undefined, no se que esta sucediendo.

Comment: Pero que modificación sugerida  hiciste?? Hacer un consolé.log() en tu ejemplo obviamente va dar undefined

Comment: hice las 3 sugerencias y con cada una hice un console.log() para ver si el data se encontraba en la variable que estaba asignando.

Comment: Muéstranos lo que hiciste... Y como lo hiciste... Si no lo vemos no podemos ayudarte

Comment: @Gustavo nuevamente estas tratando de modificar la respuesta. si necesitas clarificar algo debes usar la seccion de comentarios o editar tu pregunta.